# Не компилится solidity

Tags: c++, компиляция

Компилирую вот по этому [ману](http://github.com/moneroexamples/compile-cpp-ethereum-on-arch).
Вылетает такая ошибка:

```
[ 25%] Building CXX object libsolidity/CMakeFiles/solidity.dir/codegen/CompilerUtils.cpp.o
/home/dar/solidity/libsolidity/codegen/CompilerUtils.cpp: В функции-члене «void dev::solidity::CompilerUtils::convertType(const dev::solidity::Type&, const dev::solidity::Type&, bool, bool, bool)»:
/home/dar/solidity/libsolidity/codegen/CompilerUtils.cpp:788:3: ошибка: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
   }
   ^
/home/dar/solidity/libsolidity/codegen/CompilerUtils.cpp:790:2: замечание: here
  default:
  ^~~~~~~
cc1plus: все предупреждения считаются ошибками
make[2]: *** [libsolidity/CMakeFiles/solidity.dir/build.make:543: libsolidity/CMakeFiles/solidity.dir/codegen/CompilerUtils.cpp.o] Ошибка 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:275: libsolidity/CMakeFiles/solidity.dir/all] Ошибка 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Ошибка 2
```

Что могло пойти не так?

Comment: править код не очень хорошая идея, как можно отключить? makefile?

Comment: В смысле "Что могло пойти не так?" Компилятор говорит, что предыдущая ветка `switch` не завершена `break`. Пока настройки компилятора сделаны так, что это считается ошибкой, код компилироваться не будет. Крутите настройки. Откуда взялось `-Werror=implicit-fallthrough`? Было или вы сами добавили?

Comment: надо в makefile что то подправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас включён флаг `-Werror`. Его можно отключить целиком (найти поиском в CMakeList), или отключить конкретную проверку, добавив `-Wno-error=implicit-fallthrough` к флагам компиляции. Ну или можно подправить исходники, чтобы для каждого `case` был свой `break`.

Кроме того, если я правильно понял, это только на gcc-7 работает, разработчики добавили флаг в основном в связи с добавлением в C++17 атрибута `[[fallthrough]]`. Из-за этого добавление `-Wno-error=implicit-fallthrough` приведет к сбою для более старых версий gcc.